# Class constructor AnimationEngine cannot be invoked without new

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to initiate an ionic application with the command "ionic serve". When the application loads, I see the following message:
"Class constructor AnimationEngine cannot be invoked without new".
AnimationEngine refers to auto-generated files of the application, so I am not able to change them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
npm i @angular/platform-browser@latest --save
npm i @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest --save
```

My problem is that my versions of platform-browser were old.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was in Angular `12`, that for some reason `@angular/animations` version was `13`. Downgrading it to same version `12` like other angular related packages solved the issue.